# Passport blank page requirements for Kurdistan

Tags: passports, uk-citizens, iraqi-kurdistan

How many consecutive blank pages are required in a UK passport for (1) entry to Kurdistan for a citizen from a visa free entry country together with (2) a short-term residency permit for Kurdistan?

I am aware that at least part of the documentation connected with a residency permit may be surrendered on departure. Also of this hilarious but somewhat alarming, though now elderly, blog post: [Wandering Earl.com](http://www.wanderingearl.com/visiting-the-directorate-of-residence-in-kurdistan/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a post on the [Lonely Planet forums](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/europe-eastern-europe-the-caucasus/topics/passport-pages-visas-georgia-armenia-iraqi-kurdistan-azerbaijan-turke) last year:

> ... AZerbaidjan full page, Armenia full page, **Iraqui Kurdistan stamp**
>   (so two stamps almost a page), Turkey two small stamps (may be half a
>   page), Georgia same (two small stamps, entry and exit another half
>   page). I dont expecvt these practices changed though cannot verify. 
>   ...

sounds like they only have stamps, so would fit on one page.

Note that a google image search shows the [Iraqi one being a simple stamp as well for a visa](http://www.vagabondjourney.com/photos/1077-iraq-visa-stamp.JPG) and this blogger [shows his Kurdistan visa as a stamp as well](http://www.joaoleitao.com/iraqikurdistan/visa-to-iraq-republic-kurdistan-region/).

[Another photo](http://www.joaoleitao.com/viagens/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/visto-iraque-passaporte.jpg) with yet [another on a blog](http://www.aaronswwadventures.com/2012/07/kurdistan-other-iraq/) pointing out that if you want to extend the 10 days limit, "You ONLY have to visit the Directorate of Residence if you want to extend your visa and stay beyond 10 days. ".

So even if a 'short term residence permit' from this office comes to a full page, which Iraq seems to do, then you'll need at maximum two pages.

Comment: @pnuts sounds sketchy there at present, saw many warnings in my search, be careful.  Keep us posted, and a photo would be great. I've also learned it's surprisingly easy to search for visas in passports now on google images, will be using that in future ;)